# PHP returning an element from an array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have some code that returns all the time in an array like this **Open hours today: 9:00- 9:45, 9:55 - 10:20, 10:30 - 11:00** . If we used $formatted_ranges[array_key_first($formatted_ranges)] instead of join, it would return a single element as like this, "Open hours today: 9:00 - 9:45". However we need to return like this,

Open hours today: 9:00 - 11:00.

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i', $range['from'] );
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i', $range['to'] );

$formatted_ranges = array_map( function( $range ) {
            return $this->format_time( $range['from'] ).' - '.$this->format_time($range['to'] );
}, $ranges );

return sprintf(
  __( 'Open hours today:', 'example' ) . ' <span>%s</span>',
            join( ', ', $formatted_ranges )
        );
```

Comment: The code you provided cannot be run. Can you please formulate a piece of code that can properly run to demonstrate your issue? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it cannot run because this is just a piece from a very long code. I was wondering if you had any ideas to guide me to solve this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: It is very hard to answer your question without code example. You do not need to paste your whole thing, but you need to trim down your code to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can follow up on. At least write a self-contained function would be a good start.

Comment: sukkie: To produce a PHP array code from the values, you can use `var_export($ranges, TRUE);`. You can then easily copy the output and paste it here as the function input.

Comment: Are the rows in `$ranges` always pre-sorted ASC? or do you need to sort the times after formatting?  Is there a reason that you can't just take the `from` element of the first row and the `to` element from the last row?  Formatting every element when you only need 2 looks like unnecessary work to me.

Comment: @mickmackusa no, we do not need to format them. I just did that as an example.

Comment: So you are asking how to access `$ranges[0]['from']` and `$ranges[array_last_key($ranges)]['to']`?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks it's working :) Would you mind explaining why it would be ranges and not formatted_ranges? Thanks

Comment: @mickmackusa also it would be array_key_last right not the other way around? thanks

Comment: @suk yes, I got the function name wrong (because I didn't test my suggestion).  I've posted a working solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the input data correctly, you don't need to iterate and reformat every element in the multidimensional array.

Just access the `from` from the first row and the `to` from the last row and you're done.  Format just those two values if necessary.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7BS1d))

```
$ranges = [
    ['from' => '9:00', 'to' => '9:45'],
    ['from' => '9:55', 'to' => '10:20'],
    ['from' => '10:30', 'to' => '11:00'],
];

if (!isset($ranges[0]['from'], $ranges[0]['to'])) {
    throw new Exception('insufficient business hours data');
}
printf(
    'Open hours today: %s - %s',
    $ranges[0]['from'],
    $ranges[array_key_last($ranges)]['to']
);
```

Output:

```
Open hours today: 9:00 - 11:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The originally shared code was not runnable. From the question, I think you want to reformat a time range array to find the beginning and the end of all the ranges.

As long as all the time are represented as 24-hour clock format, this is an example of how it can be done.

```php
<?php

/**
 * Convert multiple ranges into a single range.
 *
 * @param array $ranges
 * @return array
 */
function overallRanges(array $ranges): array {
  if (sizeof($ranges) === 0) {
    throw new \Exception('The provided ranges array is empty');
  }
  $range = array_reduce($ranges, function ($carry, $current) {
    $from = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $current['from']);
    $to = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $current['to']);
    $carry['from'] = ($from < $carry['from']) ? $from : $carry['from'];
    $carry['to'] = ($to > $carry['to']) ? $to : $carry['to'];
    return $carry;
  },
    [
      'from' => DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $ranges[0]['from']),
      'to' => DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $ranges[0]['to']),
    ]
  );
  return [
    'from' => $range['from']->format('G:i'),
    'to' => $range['to']->format('G:i'),
  ];
}

// example use
$ranges = [
  ['from' => '9:00', 'to' => '9:45'],
  ['from' => '9:55', 'to' => '10:20'],
  ['from' => '10:30', 'to' => '11:00'],
];

var_dump(overallRanges($ranges));
```

The output:

```
array(2) {
  ["from"]=>
  string(5) "9:00"
  ["to"]=>
  string(5) "11:00"
}
```

Should be a good enough start for you to reformat into anything.